How to add Google Drive image to Google Slides, using a script?
I'm trying to use a script to add an image saved in my Drive into my presentation (Google Slides).
The image is a JPG, and it is less than 50 MB.
The script I'm using to do it is the following:
function addImageToSlide() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById("PRESENTATION ID");
  var slide = presentation.appendSlide(SlidesApp.PredefinedLayout.BLANK);

  var imgId = "IMAGE ID";
  var url = `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${imgId}`;
  var logo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();

  try {
    var image = slide.insertImage(logo);

    // Obter dimensões da página
    var pageWidth = presentation.getPageWidth();
    var pageHeight = presentation.getPageHeight();

    // Centralizar imagem
    image.setLeft(pageWidth / 2 - image.getWidth() / 2);
    image.setTop(pageHeight / 2 - image.getHeight() / 2);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log("An error occurred: ", err);
  }
}

However, it keeps returning an error:
An error occurred:  { [Exception: The image you are trying to use is invalid or corrupt.] name: 'Exception' }

I've tried to use the image thumbnail to insert it into the presentation, and it worked.
But the quality is very poor, so I'm still trying a approach that returns me a good resolution image.
What's wrong with the code or the image?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can't tell you what is wrong with the image because there aren't details about it. First, download it and try to open it using a local image viewer.  Check the file size and dimensions.

If you are using multiple account sign-in, start over using your browser in incognito / private mode. Ensure that you only sign in using one account.

If the jpg dimensions are too big or have a huge resolution, create a smaller image.

Even when creating a smaller version, the error is the same.

Try using a different format like PNG. P.D. This site's Q&A structure is designed to avoid extended discussions and file sharing. Questions and answers should be self-contained and focused on a practical, detailed programming problem. Once you earn 20 reputation points, you might access the [chat], which has a different structure and rules, but there is no guarantee that there will be a chatroom with people willing to help with all the troubleshooting problems.

Method chaining makes it hard to debug. To make it easier, by changing
From:
var logo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();

To:
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
if(response.getResponseCode() === 200){
  var logo = response.getBlob();
} else {
  throw new Error(response.getContentText());
}

Note: There are easier ways to insert an image from Google Drive.
Example
/**
 * Insert an image hosted in Google Drive on a slide of the active presentation. By default, the image is inserted on the first slide.
 * @param {number} slideIndex Zero based slide index
 * @param {string} fileId File ID of an image hosted in Google Drive. This function assumes that the effective user has access to the image.  
 */
function insertImageFromDrive(slideIndex = 0, fileId = "IMAGE_ID"){
 const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
 const blob = file.getBlob();
 const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
 const slides = presentation.getSlides();
 const slide = slides[slideIndex];
 slide.insertImage(blob); 
}

You might replace IMAGE_ID with the file ID of the image to use by default / for unit testing.
Related

Cannot insert image into Google Slides using app script
Insert Image by URL Doesn't Work in Google Apps Script


I've tried both your codes, but the error is still the same:
Exception: The image you are trying to use is invalid or corrupt.

@HenriqueFelipetto, you need to check that you are using the right image ID and that the image is not too big, among other things.

Actually, I've checked that. It's the right ID; I can access the image by opening a new tab in a different browser and inserting the image URL.
I've tried the same code, but with some images available online (like the ones from Wikipedia), and the code worded successfully.
It only fails when I'm trying to use my own Drive images.
